# How can I initialize objects in a dynamically allocated array with some arguments

Tags: c++

I wonder how to initialize each object in a dynamically allocated array with some arguments.

I'm aware of that how to initialize all objects in a dynamically allocated array with a default constructor.

For example, Suppose there is a class named Circle, which has a member variable named radius.
I know

`Circle *arr=new Circle[5]`

means a Circle object is constructed by the default constructor.

But how can I do some work like this? (though this doesn't work.)

**`Circle *arr=new Circle[5](10)`**

Following is the whole code that you can refer to.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Circle
{
private:
    int radius;
public:
    Circle(int r)
    {
        cout << "radius : " << r << endl;
        this->radius = r;
    }
    Circle()
    {
        cout << "radius : 0" << endl;
        this->radius = 0;
    }

    ~Circle()
    {
        cout << "deleted" << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Circle *arr = new Circle[5];
    // Here, What I want is something like this
    // Circle *arr = new Circle[5](10) //10 would be an argument meaning radius

    delete[] arr;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: `std::vector<Circle> arr(5, 10)` will do the job, without the need for explicitly using dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Thank you. I knew vector but just wondered if array could implement those work. Thank you very much!!

Comment: why dont you want to use the default contructor? The default constructor is the contructor that default constructs an object, so if you want default constructed objects to have some default values thats the place to put them

Comment: I worried about some cases when users input data.

Comment: @Peter Still answering in comments I see :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - my previous comment mentioned an alternative, and didn't actually answer the question as asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use std::vector.

If you still want to use arrays, you can use

`Circle *arr = new Circle[5]{10};` which initializes first radius to 10 and use default for others.

Sample output will be:

```
radius : 10
radius : 0
radius : 0
radius : 0
radius : 0
deleted
deleted
deleted
deleted
deleted
```

If you want a single line solution you can use this dirty line:

`Circle *arr = new Circle[5]{10,10,10,10,10};`

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem.

I wondered if I can implement those work by using arrays.

But I figured out I can make it by using std::vector

`vector<Circle> arr(num,Circle(radius))`

and then, constructor `Circle(int r)` is invoked **only once**

copy constructor `Circle(Circle& c)` is invoked **multiple times**.

Thank you!